# Equivalence with 3 variables, how to simplify?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How do I simplify with equivalence/implication laws when I have 3 terms and 2
logical connectives? See my example.

$$ (p \lor (p \land q \land \lnot r)) $$

I would guess its like this with the distributive law:

$$ (p \lor p) \land (p \lor q) \land (p \lor \lnot r) $$

But I have a feeling this is wrong? How do I use different laws to simplify "clauses" like this?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you feel this is wrong? Remember, $\land$ (logical and) is associative.

Comment: This is entirely true, and the justification (using the distributive law) is completely correct.

Comment: I haven't had any tasks with 3 terms and it's not mentioned somewhere in the book, and my teacher hasn't gone through it. 
Is this right so I can continue with the task from there? 
I didn't use the associative law because the ∧'s are in opposite direction?

Comment: Okay, thank you!! Then I continue from there

Comment: Just like other people said in the comments, it's valid. I think your confusion is working with $3$ variables. I suggest you to think as follow: you certainly know that \begin{equation*} a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee c).\end{equation*}In the example you stated, all you to do is to define (for example) $a = p$; $b = (p \wedge q)$ and $c = \lnot r$. It is the exact same as working with two terms! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I would guess you can also use the absorption law directly? (∨(∧∧¬)) => only p? The distributive law just seems like a detour when I did the whole "equation"?

Answer (score 1):

Your reformulation of the proposition is correct. An even simpler reformulation would be

$p\lor (0\land q \land \lnot r)$

$\iff p\lor (0)$

$\iff p$

This is also achieved by using the "lemma" in my previous answer to your previous question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm gonna go through your answer on my other question tomorrow.
Yes I'm aware how to simplify from there, it was the three variables that confused me.

Comment: @Sara I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @peterwhy you're right, I'm dumb. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I would guess you can also use the absorption law directly? (∨(∧∧¬)) => only p? The distributive law just seems like a detour when I did the whole "equation"

Comment: @Sara yes, the absorption law would give the same answer, namely that the whole proposition is actually equivalent to just $p$